# Can't assign new value to django model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a `calculation = models.FloatField(default=0)` field and I am trying to assign new value(according to debuger its 32) to it like this:

```
   def calculate(**kwargs):
       row = ContractorScoring.objects.select_related('client', 'lead', 'budgetOptions', 'techCompatibility',
                                               'availableMen', 'degreeOfElaboration', 'geography',
                                               'nonInHouseReady', 'existingItPartner', 'httpsAvailability',
                                               'monthlyAdsBudget', 'mobilePageLoadSpeed', 'desktopPageLoadSpeed',
                                               'organicTraficTrend', 'payedTraficTrend', 'techStackEquality',
                                               'projectType', 'customerReadiness', 'servicesMeet')

       points_sum = float(row[0].budgetOptions.points + row[0].techCompatibility.points +
                   row[0].availableMen.points + row[0].degreeOfElaboration.points +
                   row[0].geography.points + row[0].nonInHouseReady.points +
                   row[0].existingItPartner.points + row[0].httpsAvailability.points +
                   row[0].monthlyAdsBudget.points + row[0].mobilePageLoadSpeed.points +
                   row[0].desktopPageLoadSpeed.points + row[0].organicTraficTrend.points +
                   row[0].payedTraficTrend.points + row[0].techStackEquality.points +
                   row[0].projectType.points + row[0].customerReadiness.points + row[0].servicesMeet.points)

       row[0].calculation = points_sum
       print(str(row[0].calculation))
       row[0].save(update_fields=['calculation'])

       return row[0].calculation
```

And when I print `row[0].calculation` value it gives me my default value 0,0.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please see how to write a [mre].

Comment: How do you imagine yourself a minimum reproducible example that should include 20 tables? I have added the whole method body, but as far as I see, that's all I can share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be modifying a model instance that's still in a queryset (`row[0]`, where `row` is thus kind of a misnomer).

Instead, grab the object itself:

```
def calculate(**kwargs):
    scoring = ContractorScoring.objects.select_related(...).first()
    points_sum = float(scoring.a + scoring.b + ...)
    scoring.calculation = points_sum
    scoring.save(update_fields=["calculation"])
    return scoring.calculation
```

Do note that you're missing any sort of filter on the `ContractorScoring` query, so there's no guarantee at all which object of the various ContractorScorings you might have you're going to get! That's likely not what you want.

Comment: Is it immutable while in QuerySet?

Comment: @Void a queryset is evaluated lazily. So when you were writing `row[0]` you were making a separate query to the database each time.

Comment: Ok, now I see. So corset is something like a SQL query that wasn't being yet executed.